# ASP.net help with auto refresh web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working on a web project where I am required to display data from a interbase database into a grid view. however this data is constantly changing, iv managed to query the database and display the data into a grid view. I am now stuck on how I can automatically refresh the page after 5 minutes so that the new data is queried and displayed.

Can you please advice on how I may achieve the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not using AJAX, you can set a [`META` refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag to reload the page every 5 minutes.

If you do use AJAX, you can set a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) to refetch the data.

Comment: im not using AJAX, can you provide me with a article on how i may set a timer to every 5 minutes the web page will do perform the Page_Load function.

Comment: @c11ada - I linked to relevant web pages. What you want needs to be done _client_ side, not _server_ side. Having it on `page_load` will not do anything for you.

Comment: iv decided to use the META refresh tag, however Im having a slight problem Im using a master page and I dont want all the pages to refresh after 5 mins just one of them. obviously you cant put META tags in pages that derive from a master page ?!

Comment: @c11ada - You are right, this is not possible. You can put a `literal` control on the master header and in your specific content page set it to a META tag.

Comment: sorry im really new to ASP.NET developing can you explain how i might do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Put the GridView inside an `UpdatePanel` and use a `Timer`.

Here are some links.

http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/timer-control/
http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/using_the_ajax_timer_control_a.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can set the META refresh in a page that derives from the Master Page, you just need to add it on the code in PreRender

```
HtmlGenericControl ctrl = new HtmlGenericControl("meta");
ctrl.Attributes["http-equiv"] = "refresh";
ctrl.Attributes["content"] = "300";
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the page, with the following META tag in the HEAD section

```
<META http-equiv = "refresh" URL = "default.html" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [timer control](http://www.infoa2z.com/asp.net/how-to-auto-refresh-a-web-page-every-two-minutes) in update panel, set the interval, call a server side event on timer_Tick event, page will refresh at regular interval. Interval is in miliseconds.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="TimedPanel" updatemode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateTimer" eventname="Tick" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Timer runat="server" id="UpdateTimer" interval="2000"  OnTick="Timer1_Tick"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

In default.aspx page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- For auto refresh cause use this section-->
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;url=../account/default.aspx">
<title></title>
</head>
```

In code behind default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", 30 + "; URL=../account/default.aspx");
}
```

This web page will automatically refresh every 30s.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can write a javascript timer and then refresh the page. Cant recollect the syntax but it should be something like window.location.reload or window.form.reload. You attach the javascript timer function at the end of the Page_Load function.

Comment: Check the Meta tag as mentioned by @Oded. This one is an old school solution!